# batch organize import in eclipse cdt plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse cdt plugin for c/c++ have a feature to organize header files (like java organize imports) and get rid of unused header files. Once the C/C++ file is open I can use this feature using organize imports. Is it possible to automate this task? I have 1000s of C files that I need to pass through CDT and get rid of unused header files.

I'm thinking to write an eclipse plugin that will:
- open one file at a time from the list I provide
- organize header files
- and save it back

does anyone know of an easier and quicker way to do it?

Comment: Don't think it's possible in the current version of Eclipse. Maybe make a contribution to the CDT project?